# What is the largest size a HashSet or TreeSet be?

Tags: java, data-structures

So I am working on a solo project that involves **a lot** of strings. In one of my smaller test cases there will be *at least* 70 million elements. So my question is, what is the largest possible size a TreeSet or a HashSet can reach until it can no longer grow **OR** until it reaches a size that it can no longer be feasible to use in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Have you looked at the code for the various sets?  You may also want to look at writing your own data structures that may be better suited to your problem (which is currently poorly descrived).

Comment: @MichaelT What I understood from the Java docs is that the maximum size is around 2^30 (can't remember off the top of my head) but when my collection grows large enough it usually stops expanding around 8.6 million objects. I will look into creating my own data structure. Thanks for the advice

Comment: arrays can be size 2<sup>31</sup>-1 elements in Java. A hash-based structure uses an array, but elements can be chained. Might be worth looking into what happens when the size is too large. Non-array-based collections can theoretically be larger, but at that point the realistic performance is worse than the Big-Oh says in theory.

Comment: Notice that 70Mstrings of e.g. 10 chars each consume about 70M*40 bytes (IIRC, the overhead for each Java string is nearly 30 bytes) So you need 3GBytes of RAM just for your strings.

Comment: Maybe a reasonable thing might be to make an array of hashsets, e.g. by "hashing" the array using e.g. the hash of the first 4 bytes....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch there are quite a few possible solutions to this, though that in part depends on what you want to do.  The right answer might be a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the data, that is backed by a custom string class that allows a substring to reduce backing memory.  Or a DFA recognizing the language of the 70M elements, or something else that allows you to do the `contains` of a `Set` against all the permutations of a String without actually storing all the Strings. This question feels very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213963)

Comment: @MichaelT I looked at Trie and it doesn't seem optimal for my purpose. the overhead is what is killing me than. I will have to do this in sequences instead. In my case, I wouldn't be able to fit my targeted goal of strings. I will have to do this in chunks and write everything that was a previously computed to the disk.

Comment: @fatso113 The trie is one of *many* data structures designed for woking with Strings.  Without knowing more about your strings and the problem, there is no way that we can say what will or will not work for approaching the problem of storage and computation of these strings.  Just trying to stuff it all in a Set is probably the wrong answer no matter how many elements the Set can contain.

Answer (score 3):

If just allocating objects for your smaller test cases are using several GB of RAM, and many small objects, you are right to worry about your larger cases.

I would sit down and think carefully about your data needs for a larger test case.  If it is pushing what you are comfortable with, I would radically restructure your program.  For inspiration, read http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html and think through how to implement a toy version using the standard Unix sort utility.  (Warning, you need to set the locale to C for it to Do The Right Thing.)

I have personally written programs that used "toy" versions like that to process billions of data points on a single machine in a matter of hours.  If you have a real cluster available to you with something like Hadoop, then the only limit is the size of your cluster.  (With AWS available to you, that is entirely a question of how much you want to spend.)

If you wind up "at internet scale", remember that the key to scalability is to do a map-reduce to map data from one distributed data store to another.  That way there is fault-tolerance everywhere (in your data store and in your map-reduce framework) and no bottlenecks.  What you never, ever, want to do is collect data on a single machine.

Admittedly this involves completely rethinking your program.  But if you'll need to EVENTUALLY, might as well do it now when that is less work!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, yet Hadoop would not help with my problem and I should have been more clear from the start. Basically I have the characters AbCd and I want to get every possible string from that input with size of 3 for example. When the time comes that I need to get size 10 of the input, than I am facing a problem with a size that has increased exponentially. Hadoop was interesting, thank you for pointing to it and letting me learn something new for today. I have found a work around for myself so I can save space. Thank you for the input